# iOS MAilCore: How can i download mail attachments and show it in a webview?

Tags: iphone, ios, email, ios6, mailcore

I am new to iOS development. I am using **MailCore** to get emails in my application. My **xcode version is 4.6.3 and iOS:6.1 and 5.1**. Can anyone help me to sort out my problem. I get the mails from my server with attachment count and description, but i didn't find a way to download this file or **how can i fetch the attached file**.

Please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

it's very simple:

first of all - get messages uid's

```
MCOIndexSet *uidSet = [MCOIndexSet indexSetWithRange:MCORangeMake(1,UINT64_MAX)];//for all msgs
MCOIMAPSession *session = <new or reuse IMAP session, i reuse this>
MCOIMAPFetchMessagesOperation *fetchOp =
[session fetchMessagesByUIDOperationWithFolder:@"INBOX"
                                    requestKind:MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindFullHeaders
                                           uids:uidSet];

[fetchOp start:^(NSError *err, NSArray *messagesList, MCOIndexSet *vanished) {
    if (!err) {            
        NSLog(@"Receive %i messages",(int)[messagesList count]);
        NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"header.date" ascending:NO];
//upd UI
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotif_postCollector_ReceiveMessages object:nil];
//store msgs
        [[DataSingleton sharedSingleton] updateMessageListWithMessages:[messagesList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]]];
    }else{
        //oh no
    }
}];
```

second - get structure of messages (NOT all, just needed - array messagesList)

```
MCOIndexSet *uidSet = [MCOIndexSet indexSet];
for (Message *message in messagesList)// i use this class to store msgs. mcUid = MailCore Uid
    [uidSet addIndex:[[message mcUid] integerValue]];

MCOIMAPSession *session = <new or reuse IMAP session, i reuse this>
MCOIMAPFetchMessagesOperation *fetchOp =
[session fetchMessagesByUIDOperationWithFolder:@"INBOX"//or another folder
                                   requestKind:MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindStructure
                                          uids:uidSet];

[fetchOp start:^(NSError *err, NSArray *messagesList, MCOIndexSet *vanished) {

    if (!err) {

        NSLog(@"Receive %i messages with structures",(int)[messagesList count]);
        NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"header.date" ascending:NO];
        //store attachment precence
        [[DataSingleton sharedSingleton] updateAttachmentsPresenceForMessages:[messagesList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]]
                                                            forAccount:acc];
/* You get array of this objects:
MCOIMAPPart : MCOAbstractPart
//A part identifier looks like 1.2.1
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * partID;
//The size of the single part in bytes
@property (nonatomic, nonatomic) unsigned int size;
//It's the encoding of the single part
@property (nonatomic, nonatomic) MCOEncoding encoding;
*/
    }
}];
```

and step number 3 and final step:

```
MCOIMAPSession *session = <new or reuse IMAP session, i reuse this>
int uid = [[message mcUid] intValue];
NSString *partID = [attachment mcPartID];//we stored it on step 2
MCOIMAPFetchContentOperation * op = [session     fetchMessageAttachmentByUIDOperationWithFolder:@"INBOX"
  uid:uid
  partID:partID
  encoding:(MCOEncoding)[[attachment mcEncoding] integerValue]];

NSLog(@"download att %i part %@",uid,partID);
[op start:^(NSError * error, NSData * messageData) {

    if (error) {

    }else{
        TRACE(@"receive att %i part %@",uid,partID);
        //save attachment fo local disc
        [[DataSingleton sharedSingleton] updateDownloadedAttachment:attachment
                                                           withData:messageData];
    }
}];
```

more info on [GitHub](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2) and official page [libmailcore.com](http://libmailcore.com/)

Comment: Hi, can you post your DataSingleton class? Thank you

Comment: @sundsx Sorry, but no. It it NDA protected. What are you want to know?

Comment: Hi, winsergey. i would like follow your example for storing attachment. so for example:
updateAttachmentsPresenceForMessages and updateDownloadedAttachment are array or nsdata object ?

Comment: @sundsx answer to your question:https://gist.github.com/b5684c470e877af75880 https://gist.github.com/ba53ef49818ea6db79be

Comment: You Are a Big Man! Thank you WINSergey.

Comment: i want something that display the attachment in webview and on tap on that it will downloaded.... do you have something like this?? please help me

Comment: @Patel Jigar try to use webView for html's, ImageView for images etc. It is the general answer but you ask general question. For this purpose I need more information about your case.

Comment: actually i am creating mail app so i need something that shows all the attachmants with body just like ios mail app shows, and download the attachment on tap of each attachment

Comment: dear @Patel Jigar please check my answer above: download messages, update presence of attachment and when user tap on it -> download and show.

Answer (score 0):

```
            MCOMessageParser * msg = [MCOMessageParser messageParserWithData:data];

            if ([_message.attachments count] > 0)
            {
                for (int i=0; i<[_message.attachments count]; ++i)
                {
                    MCOIMAPPart *part = [_message.attachments objectAtIndex:i];

                    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                    NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                                          docDir, [part filename]];
                    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
                    if (NO == fileExists) {
                        [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
                    }
                }
            }
```